# "Command hooks failed" when deploying Django on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i'm trying to deploy a Django app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. Following amazon's [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html), i changed my database settings to RDS and wrote a config file.

This is in django's settings.py:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
    'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
    'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
    'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
    'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
}
```

and this is my config file for Elastic Beanstalk:

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:    
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_createadmin:
    command: "scripts/createadmin.py"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: myapp/wsgi.py
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
    option_name: /static/
    value: static/
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: myapp.settings
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    value: *my secret key*
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: *my access key*
```

I'm using eb to deploy. With "eb init" and "eb start" i can successfully create the app and it's env and with git aws.push i'm pushing my last commit to the server.

However, after it updates i got this error:

```
2014-07-03 13:41:27 UTC-0300    ERROR   [Instance: i-4b1aef3e Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed .
2014-07-03 13:41:25 UTC-0300    ERROR   Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01new.py failed with returncode 1
2014-07-03 13:41:25 UTC-0300    ERROR   Application version failed to deploy.
```

What i'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

[This is the log of a deploy](http://pastebin.com/L5Wj8vrv)

Comment: What changes did you push in your last commit?
Can you try snapshot logs to see detailed error messages: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html?

Comment: @RohitBanga i updated with a snapshot log. I already looked it but didn't noticed anything that explains this error. The "last commit" indeed was the "first commit" for this app.

Comment: what do you get when you do `eb status --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are trying to push: `git aws.push` from your virtualenv or where you have python installed. Also, you should try restarting the EC2 machine that powers your ElasticBeanstalk application.